# How to find using JPQL if member value is in a collection of values

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, jpql

I have an object in which a member is an enum, and I want to write a query returning all elements for which that member is in a list of values. So, I've written the following JQP query

```
@NamedQuery(name = MyBean.FIND_BY_STATUSES, query = "select t from "+MyBean.TABLE+" t where t.status member of :statuses"),
class MyBean {
     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     private MyEnum status;
}
```

That I try to get using the following EJB code

```
    Query findByStatuses = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(MyBean.FIND_BY_STATUSES);
    findByStatuses.setParameter("statuses", Arrays.asList(statuses));
    return findByStatuses.getResultList();
```

Unfortunatly, Glassfish endlessly tells me I'm wrong (which I am, obviously).
But what do I have to fix ? and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your query references to table name, so it tries to be kind of SQL, but maybe database does not have "MEMBER OF"-operator which would be suitable for this kind of use, so let's try with JPQL. There we cannot use MEMBER OF, because it takes path expression as an argument, and that is not what we provide in setParameter. Instead we use IN:

```
@NamedQuery(name = MyBean.FIND_BY_STATUSES, query = "select t from MyBean t where t.status in(:statuses)")
```

No need to modify part where you run query.